# Matrix $\log(\exp(M))\ne M$?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

I have tested matrix $\log$ following matrix $\exp$ in many different math libraries (**Eigen** for C++, **numpy** for Python, and yet other less known implementations) and for most square matrices M we have $\log(\exp(M))=M$, which is expected.

Now it turns out that in some cases $\log(\exp(M))\ne M$.

e.g. for

$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -6 &  5 & 1 \\
 6 &  0 & -4 & 2 \\
-5 &  4 &  0 & 3 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**all libraries** return

$$
\log(\exp(M))=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0          & -1.70378748 &  1.4198229 & 1.47425723 \\
 1.70378748 &  0          & -1.1358583 & 2.05579497 \\
-1.4198229  &  1.13585832 &  0         & 2.6373327  \\
 0          &  0          &  0         & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Any idea of what is going on and why I am not getting $M$ as a result?

Note that in my case $M$ is an element of $\operatorname{se}(3)$, the *special euclidean algebra* (not sure whether this is important...).

**------ EDIT ------**

This behavior seems to  be due to $\exp$ being many-to-one (modulo $2\pi$) though this is in contradiction with what is observed here:

Let $\overline M$ be the compact representation of $M$, hence

$$
\overline M=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So $\left\|\overline M \right\|=9.53939201417$, and thus $\overline M$ is not the principal representation of the log. We obviously expect $\log(\exp(M))$ to be the principal representation, but it turns out it is not, because
$$
\left\|\overline {\log(\exp(M))} \right\|=4.42314527494 \neq 9.53939201417 [2\pi]
$$

and it also turns out that

$$
\frac{\overline M}{\left\|\overline M \right\|} \neq \frac{\overline {\log(\exp(M))}}{\left\|\overline {\log(\exp(M))} \right\|}
$$

as

$$
\frac{\overline M}{\left\|\overline M \right\|} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.10482848 & 0.20965697 & 0.31448545 & 0.41931393 & 0.52414242 & 0.6289709
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but

$$
\frac{\overline {\log(\exp(M))}}{\left\|\overline {\log(\exp(M))} \right\|} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.33330518 & 0.46478125 & 0.59625731 & 0.25679878 & 0.32099848 & 0.38519817
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Why not try a simpler example: $\pmatrix{0&-6\cr 6&0}$ maybe?

Comment: That shouldn't actually be a surprise: for instance even just the matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{C}$, and the matrix exponential and the complex one agree. It is well known that the complex exponential is many-to-one.

Comment: Writing \log and \exp not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $3\log5$ and $3\exp5$ and $3\log(5)$ and $3\exp(5).$ In include those last two examples so that you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing: how much space is on the left or the right side depends on what is on that side. It is standard usage and I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The eigenvalues of the original matrix are $0,0,\pm i\sqrt{77}$, which is likely significant.

Comment: Did you try $\exp\log\exp M$ to see if it's the same as $\exp M\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: With a similarity transformation, you can distinguish these nested classes of cases, getting worse progressively:
1) Reals
2) Matrices with real eigenvalues
3) Matrices with complex eigenvalues
4) Nondiagonalizable matrices (reduced to Jordan canonical form)
Consider what property you lose at each step.

Comment: @Ian: do you mean that the libraries I have used have interpreted M as a complex matrix and that there is some sort of modulo on the result of the complex $\exp$?

Comment: @Chappers: I am not sure to understand what these eigenvalues imply... Can you shed some light?

Comment: @arennuit No, I'm just saying that the same many-to-one property held by the complex exponential is held by the matrix exponential in dimension higher than 2. A simple example: $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \pi \\ 2 \pi & 0 \end{bmatrix},\exp(A)=I$ hence for the principal matrix logarithm $\log(\exp(A))=0$. This corresponds to the fact that the solutions of the ODE system $x'=-y,y'=x$ are $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: As Chappers points out, the eigenvalues of $M$ are 0, 0, $i\sqrt{77}$ and $-i\sqrt{77}$. Using numpy to find the matrix $N = \log (\exp (M))$, we can then find the eigenvalues of $N$. These turn out to be 
0, 0, $i\sqrt{77} - 2i\pi $ and $-i\sqrt{77} + 2 i \pi$, in other words offsets have been applied to ensure that the [principal logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence)
is returned.

Comment: @Ian: thanks, I get your point! It is especially meaningful in dimension and 2 and 3, as $M$ (or your $A$) can be seen as rotation vectors... Now is the modulo also $2\pi$ for higher dimensions?

Comment: @Michael Hardy: good point, indeed $M\neq \log(\exp(M))$ but $\exp(\log(\exp(M)))=\exp(M)$ and $\log(\exp(\log(\exp(M))))=\log(\exp(M))$. This is due to the periodicity property as pointed by Ian.

Comment: @Orion: I have the feeling that your post is related to observation by Chappers, though I don't get it quite yet. Can you elaborate or give me a pointer? Your remark seem really interesting...

Comment: @Paul Aljabar: got your point! It agrees with the post by Ian.

Comment: It is sure that taking a matrix with 2 eigenvalues equal to 0, among 4 is very particular...

Comment: I have updated the main post as this $2\pi$ periodicity is not so obvious...

Comment: Not sure why the updated post is calculating matrix norms and matrix elements, since the periodicity is in the eigenvalues.  The non-zero eigenvalues of $M$ are $$\pm 8.774964387392123i$$While those of $\log(\exp(M))$ are $$\pm 2.491779080212537i$$The difference in eigenvalues is $\pm 2\pi i$.

Comment: There is obviously something I did not get here. I have posted a [new question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311897).