# Periodicity of $\log(\exp(M))$

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

Let $m_3\in so(3)$ and say

$$
m_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -6 &  5 \\
 6 &  0 & -4 \\
-5 &  4 &  0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It is well known that $\exp$ is many-to-one, hence if $n_3=\log(\exp(m_3))$, then $n_3\ne m_3$.

Now let $\overline m_3$ be the compact representation of $m_3$, hence

$$
\overline m_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now intuitively $\overline m_3$ can be interpreted as a rotation vector and getting their principal value is easy. e.g. the principal value for $\overline m_3$ is:

$$
\overline p_3=\frac{\overline m_3}{\left\| \overline m_3 \right\|}(\left\|\overline m_3 \right\| \pm 2k\pi)
$$

with $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\left\|\overline m_3 \right\| \pm 2k\pi\in]-\pi, \pi]$.

Now it seems that for higher dimensions, the behavior is not so obvious and the $2\pi$ periodicity is only in the eigen values ([my gut feeling for this intuition comes from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305935)).

So in higher dimensions, is there a way to compute the principal value of an element?

Hence say $m_6 \in se(3)$, with:

$$
m_6=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -6 &  5 & 1 \\
 6 &  0 & -4 & 2 \\
-5 &  4 &  0 & 3 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How to compute the principal value of $\overline m_6$?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is very unclear.

EDIT 1.  If $m\in so(3)$, then $spectrum(m)=\{0,ia,-ia\}$ where $a>0$ (if $a=0$ then $m=0$) and $m=Udiag(0,ia,-ia)U^*$ where $U$ is unitary.  In general, there is $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $a+2k\pi\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

If you choose the principal $\log$, then $\log(e^m)=Udiag(0,ia+2ki\pi,-ia-2ki\pi)U^*$, that is

$\log(e^m)=(1+\dfrac{2k\pi}{a})m$.

Remark. If $a\in \pi+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, then $\log(e^m)$ does not exist.

Your $M=m_6=\begin{pmatrix}m&u\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ has a double zero eigenvalue and is not diagonalizable.Then the relevant calculation is a little more complicated.

Since $M$ is similar to $diag(J_2,ia,-ia)$, it is not difficult to see that

$\log(e^M)$ is similar to $diag(J_2,ia+2ki\pi,-ia-2ki\pi)$.

Then $\log(e^M)=M-\dfrac{2k\pi}{a^3}M^3$.

Edit 2. When you calculate $\log(e^m)$, you obtain the value of $x=1+2k\pi/a$ and you deduce the principal value $p=xm$.

For the parameters of M, take $u$ and calculate $\log(e^m)$ as above.

Comment: this is very interesting, and unfortunately I know my post is not clear (because it is not clear in my head). Now can your result $\log(e^m)=m+2ki\pi Udiag(0, 1, -1)U^*$ be linked in any way to the fact that $\overline p_3$ represents the same rotation as $\overline m_3$?

Comment: Intuitively I would say your result and $\overline p_3$ ~ $\overline m_3$ are linked, but your result introduces complex numbers in the rotation vector, whereas $\overline p_3$ is not complex. What do you think?